# How can I extract the author's name and publication date using regular expression?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the author's name and publication date out of this HTML text.

Here is what I have so far:
(authorName) = ("..............")

This only works for this specific case though and I'm looking for a general approach. Could I get any tips on how to approach this?

> teacher a prime example of where SF should invest windfall";var
>   omni_bizObjectId = "13560483";var omni_className = "article";var
>   omni_publicationDate = "2019-01-25T12:00:00+00:00";var omni_sourceSite
>   ="sfgate";var omni_authorName = "Heather Knight";var omni_authorTitle = "";var omni_premiumStatus = "isPremium";var omni_premiumEndDate = "1893506400";var omni_originalSource = "SF";var omni_pageNumber =
>   "1";var omni_breakingNewsFlag = "0";var omni_localNewsFlag = "1";var
>   omni_isListView = "0";var omni_paywallSite = "1";var
>   omni_displayTemplate = "ard";

Comment: Can you add some more samples where you want to capture?

Comment: I want to capture this part: var omni_authorName = "Heather Knight"; but only the author's name if that's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture author name in group1,

```
authorName\s+=\s+"([^"]*)"
```

This regex matches `authorName` literally then one or more white space then `=` then again one or more white space then a doublequote `"` then captures any data between the next double quote and stores it in group1 which in Python can be captured using `m.group(1)`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OzvWpT/1)**

Check this Python code for how to capture data from group1,

```
import re

s = 'teacher a prime example of where SF should invest windfall";var omni_bizObjectId = "13560483";var omni_className = "article";var omni_publicationDate = "2019-01-25T12:00:00+00:00";var omni_sourceSite ="sfgate";var omni_authorName = "Heather Knight";var omni_authorTitle = "";var omni_premiumStatus = "isPremium";var omni_premiumEndDate = "1893506400";var omni_originalSource = "SF";var omni_pageNumber = "1";var omni_breakingNewsFlag = "0";var omni_localNewsFlag = "1";var omni_isListView = "0";var omni_paywallSite = "1";var omni_displayTemplate = "ard";'

m = re.search(r'authorName\s+=\s+"([^"]*)"',s)
if (m):
 print(m.group(1))
```

Prints only the author name,

```
Heather Knight
```

**Edit: Thanks to Onyambu for pointing about publicationDate.**

Just similar to `authorName`, you can use the above regex and replace `authorName` with `publicationDate` and use this regex to capture `publicationDate` as well.

```
publicationDate\s+=\s+"([^"]*)"
```

**[Demo for publicationDate](https://regex101.com/r/OzvWpT/2)**

In case you want to extract both with single regex, you can use this regex,

```
(?i).*publicationdate\s+=\s+"([^"]*)".*authorName\s+=\s+"([^"]*)"
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OzvWpT/3)**

Python codes,

```
import re

s = 'teacher a prime example of where SF should invest windfall";var omni_bizObjectId = "13560483";var omni_className = "article";var omni_publicationDate = "2019-01-25T12:00:00+00:00";var omni_sourceSite ="sfgate";var omni_authorName = "Heather Knight";var omni_authorTitle = "";var omni_premiumStatus = "isPremium";var omni_premiumEndDate = "1893506400";var omni_originalSource = "SF";var omni_pageNumber = "1";var omni_breakingNewsFlag = "0";var omni_localNewsFlag = "1";var omni_isListView = "0";var omni_paywallSite = "1";var omni_displayTemplate = "ard";'

m = re.search(r'(?i).*publicationdate\s+=\s+"([^"]*)".*authorName\s+=\s+"([^"]*)"',s)
if (m):
 print('Publication Date:', m.group(1))
 print('Author Name:', m.group(2))
```

Prints,

```
Publication Date: 2019-01-25T12:00:00+00:00
Author Name: Heather Knight
```

Comment: `(?i)(?:authorname|publicationdate)\s=\s\"[^\"]+`

Comment: @Onyambu: Ah, I just did a half answer and forgot about publicationdate. Thanks for pointing out. Let me update my answer to cover publicationdate as well.